# DynamicForm with ComboBoxItem and multiple DataSource

Tags: smartgwt, smartclient

I am new at SmartGwt. I am trying to make a DynamicForm with ComboBoxItem and I want to set combo-box values from some table in database. The DataSource which holds the form data is a different one. How can I manage this?

Here is my java code:

```
// DataSource
DataSource arcDS = DataSource.get("automaticExportConfig");
// ComboboxItem set
cycleList = new ComboBoxItem("cycle");
cycleList.setOptionDataSource(arcDS);
cycleList.setOptionOperationId("comboBoxCycleList");
cycleList.setDisplayField("cycle");
cycleList.setValueField("cycle");
cycleList.setAutoFetchData(true);
cycleList.setFilterLocally(false);
```

.ds.xml file:

```
<DataSource
  dbName="PostgreSQL"
  ID="automaticExportConfig"
  serverType="sql"
  tableName="automaticExportConfig"
  titleField="id"
>

<fields>
    <field name="id" type="sequence" sequenceName="automaticExportConfig_id_seq" hidden="true" primaryKey="true"/>
    <field name="cycle" type="text" title="Cycle"  />
    </fields>

 <operationBindings>
    <binding operationType="fetch" operationId="comboBoxCycleList" outputs="id">
        <customSQL>SELECT id FROM billingcycle</customSQL>
        <serverObject className="com.demo.server.AutomaticExportConfigDMI" methodName="getComboBoxCycleList"/>
    </binding>

</operationBindings>

<serverObject lookupStyle="new" className="com.demo.server.AutomaticExportConfigDMI"/>
```

DMI.java file:

```
public DSResponse fetch(DSRequest dsRequest) throws Exception {
    log.info("procesing AutomaticExportConfig DMI fetch operation");
    DSResponse dsResponse = dsRequest.execute();
    System.out.println("data"+dsResponse.getData());
    return dsResponse;
}

public DSResponse getComboBoxCycleList(com.isomorphic.rpc.RPCManager manager, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response, DSRequest dsRequest) throws Exception {
    log.info("procesing AutomaticExportConfig DMI fetch operation");
    DSResponse dsResponse = dsRequest.execute();
    System.out.println("listdata"+dsResponse.getData());
    return dsResponse;
}
```

Data is shown in the console, but not in the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

there is a preference to make join a file in your DataSource using `<operationBindings>` tag. Here is an example:

```
<operationBindings>
            <operationBinding operationType="fetch">
                <tableClause>crm_objects,crm_kind</tableClause>
                <whereClause>crm_objects.crm_obj_kind = crm_kind.crm_kind_idnum AND ($defaultWhereClause)</whereClause>
            </operationBinding>
        </operationBindings>
```

I hope that I have answered your question because it is not clear enough